# How fill new column with businessDuration result in Dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

please help me to solve this, How to make new column in df with duration result? also result for all row. Thanks.

````
import pandas as pd
from datetime import time,datetime
from itertools import repeat

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df['startdate_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startdate_column'])
df['enddate_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['enddate_column'])

start_time=time(8,0,0)
end_time=time(17,0,0)

unit='min'

df['Duration'] = list(map(businessDuration,startdate=df['startdate_column'],enddate=df['enddate_column'],repeat(start_time),repeat(end_time),repeat(weekendlist=[6]),repeat(unit)))```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
f = lambda x: businessDuration(startdate=x['startdate_column'],
                               enddate=x['enddate_column'],
                               starttime=start_time,
                               endtime=end_time,
                               weekendlist=[6],
                               unit=unit)

df['Duration'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```